# setting up upstream with nginx and node?

Tags: node.js, nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

I have three instances on aws. one for nginx which the front-end server, and two backend nodejs intstances.

Im trying to set up the nginx server to upstream to these node.js instances:

```
upstream node_servers {
        server private_ip:8124 weight=10 max_fails=3; // node server 1 private_ip:port
        server private_ip:8124 weight=10 max_fails=3; // node server 2 private_ip:port
}
server {
    listen  private_ip:80;     // nginx server private ip:port
    root /home/ubuntu/project/;
    server_name public_ip.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com;  // nginx public DNS
    location / {

                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
                proxy_pass http://node_servers/;

     }
}
```

on my node 1 server, node 2 server instance app.js code:

```
app.listen(8124, "127.0.0.1");
console.log("listening on 8124");
```

I go to the nginx server public domain name, and nothing really happens, its just loads forever sending request.....

Comment: You need to locate your problem: You should login in to your frontend server and try to curl the node instances: `curl http://IP:8124`, this should return something. If not check your iptables or try a standard http port like 80 or 8080.
If you get a return than you can try to upstream to just one server first. Also check you nginx logs and see if there is anything usefull there.

Comment: curl: (52) Empty reply from server, this what i get?

Comment: Have you tried setting the node port to 80? Is your firewall blocking requests? Are your node servers still bound to localhost (127.0.0.1)?

Comment: why in your example node server 1 and node server 2 have the sampe port?

Answer (score 1):

In your node code, you are listening on the loopback interface on 127.0.0.1 (requests from localhost only):

```
app.listen(8124, "127.0.0.1");
```

You have to listen on your specific private IP or 0.0.0.0:

```
app.listen(8124, "0.0.0.0");
```

Comment: You could also set it to listen on the private address making so only connections from nginx or local addresses will be accepted